# Hide Gridview column when null

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview in the front end showing 4-5 columns. Need to hide one of the column when the values are NULL.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server" BackColor="#DEBA84"
                BorderColor="#DEBA84"
                BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3"
                CellSpacing="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="100" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryId" SortExpression="CategoryId" HeaderText="CategoryId" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MerchantName" HeaderText="MerchantName" SortExpression="MerchantName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="StoreName" HeaderText="StoreName" SortExpression="StoreName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="StoreAddress" HeaderText="StoreAddress" SortExpression="StoreAddress" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True"
                    ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True"
                    ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

If I want to hide `StoreName` column from code-behind. How to achieve that ?

Comment: how do you bind data to gridview?if you can manage your selected data,then select only not null columns when StoreName is null,and set AutoGenerateColumns="True".

Comment: A column can contain multiple values, not all are necessarily null.

Comment: ALL values or One of values are NULL ???

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar: for One of values

Comment: @RahulSutar I posted answer try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use `RowDataBound` Event of `GridView`

```
protected void gridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
               string val = e.Row.Cells[0].ToString();  //check first cell value
               if(string.IsNullorEmpty(val) )             
                {
                gvSearchEngine.Columns[0].Visible = false;     //Hides First Column
                }

            }
    }
```

Comment: tried with your code, still I can see the column. See the link. The StoreName column is still blank and visible. http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1214162190672

Comment: try to Debug a Code you will get to know

Comment: i debugged the code, it is not going in IF condition

Comment: then `string.IsNullorEmpty(val)` should return true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65063/discussion-between-rahul-sutar-and-ganesh-devlekar).

Comment: but it is not going inside the IF condition of gvSearchEngine

Comment: @RahulSutar glad to help u

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can dynamically create the boundfield values
from code behind based on your requirment
follow this link
[add boundField to gridview in codebehind file C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971035/add-boundfield-to-gridview-in-codebehind-file-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

try e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0].Visible = false;